# Attempting to trace where this asset is getting called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

I see this error when I load any page on my website:

```
Started GET "/assets/star-rating.min.js.map" for ::1 at 2018-01-26 08:18:34 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/star-rating.min.js.map"):
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:22:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  rack-cors (0.4.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:81:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/deflater.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
  puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
  puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
  puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `call'
  puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'

  Rendered /Users/jeremylopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@awaken/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/jeremylopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@awaken/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (452.2ms)
Processing by ErrorsController#internal_server_error as HTML
```

but I have no idea where it's being called.  Does anyone have a good method of tracing this to find out whey it's trying to load this asset on all pages?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information on your asset pipeline? If you're doing everything through sprockets then check `application.js` - you can use process of elimination to see which `require` it comes from.

If you're loading scripts from a lot of different sources, you could use the network tab of your browser's developer tools, and see if these requests originate right after any particular script.

Answer (score 0):

That's very wired problem but need refactoring that also tough for finding where from called this.

That's mean any gem or any file are dependent or linked to this file or `application.js` requiring this `star-rating.min.js.map`, I have searched on the Google writing `star-rating.min.js.map` this but not found any file over the Google which match this `star-rating.min.js.map`.

If you find any file within your application which calling this then you must remove or comment out this.

I think you understood the point.

Comment: I found it.  Just searched my whole project for it.  The odd thing was that it seemed to already be commented out?

Comment: What happened while you remove this and make restart the server after removing